# Style.css in child theme is loaded before Bootstrap

Tags: child-theme, wp-enqueue-style, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I enqueue Bootstrap with `wp_enqueue_style()`, Bootstrap is loaded after the child theme's `style.css` and will override `style.css`.
One way to load `style.css` after Bootstrap is to enqueue `style.css` as well, but this will cause it to be loaded twice.
Any idea how to enqueue `style.css` once AND after Bootstrap?
Thanks!

Comment: Add `bootstrap.min.css` as a dependency to `style.css`. Enqueuing `bootstrap` before `style.css` is easy right, am I missing something here?

Comment: The childtheme somehow enqueues <code>style.css</code> automatically and I don't know exactly where. If I knew where, I already would have added bootstrap as a dependancy.

Comment: Search for wp_enueue_style in your theme folder. I guess the parent theme might be enqueuing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mostly the parent theme might be enqueing the child theme's `style.css`, if so you can dequeue it by using handle and then enqueue with proper dependency.

If the child theme's handle is `child-theme-style`, then dequeue it using

`wp_dequeue_style('child-theme-style')`

then enqueue it as needed like so.

```
wp_enqueue_style('child-theme-dep',get_stylesheet_uri(),array('bootstrap-handle-here'))
```

[image]

We can easily know the child theme stylesheet url by looking at the link output in the head, for example in the attached image.

```
<link rel='stylesheet' id='hybrid-style-css'  href='https://wptavern.com/wp-content/themes/stargazer-child-dev/style.css?ver=4.6.1' type='text/css' media='all' />
```

Tells us that the child theme's enqueue handle is `hybrid-style` which is the *`id`* without `-css`.

Answer (score 3):

Good news.  This is an easy fix.   WordPress allows you to declare dependencies when registering scripts and stylesheets.  Simply list the assets you wish to load earlier as dependencies for the later assets.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_style

This works for both scripts and styles and is the recommended way to control load order.